# String comparison with foreach loop. The expected output is "Facebook"

Tags: c#, string, comparison

How can we compare two elements in a string and display the most repeated value using the foreach loop?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] values = { "Facebook", "Google", "Facebook" };
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            // need to comparing the elements in the array 
            Console.WriteLine(value); /* print the repeated value*/
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Linq to accomplish this or must it be via the `foreach` loop?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with: comparing strings, counting matches, finding the string with the largest count?

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you already compare strings?

Comment: Don't you need to *finish* the loop before you know which value is the most repeated?  Your current code will print *every* string in `values`.

Comment: The string comparing must be done only in the foreach loop.

Comment: If you really, really want to do it in a foreach loop, you need to keep track of the counts of all items until you are done. And when you done, you still have to look through your keep-track-list to retrieve the most repeated value. So this cannot be the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily with LINQ

```
var mostRepeatedValue = values
                          .GroupBy(v => v)
                          .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                          .Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged as links can become broken. Further, if you believe this question is a duplicate of the one you linked in your answer, then please flag it as such. Else, then please insert the relevant code for this question :)

Comment: @Rafalon, I don't have enough reputation to flag as duplicate, I'll just copy the code from the linked answer I suppose

Comment: Well you still can make some adjustments, as the linked answer is about the **5 most repeated values**, when this question is about **the most repeated value**

Comment: You're welcome. You also could remove the `s` in `mostRepeatedValues`, and replace `ToList()` with `First` (or `FirstOrDefault`) for example so you get one value and not a list

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any way to do it with foreach loop

Comment: @Uma Manoj Devarasetti - If, for some odd reason, you must _absolutely_ use a For Each loop, please see Lucifer's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Code

```
Dictionary<string, int> stringOccurDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string[] values = { "Facebook", "Google", "Facebook" };
foreach(string x in values)
{
     if (!stringOccurDict .ContainsKey(x))
          stringOccur.Add(x, values.Count(c => values.Contains(c)));
});
string repeatedString = stringOccur.Where(x => x.Value == stringOccur.Values.Max()).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Output

```
Facebook
```

You can also  get count by using `.Value`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any way to do it with foreach loop

Comment: @UmaManojDevarasetti please check